# .net 3.5 Active Directory User creation error You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, active-directory

I am trying to create a new Active Directory user in .net 3.5 and I am recieving the following error "You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network."

1. I have googled the error and I can not find anything related to this on Windows server 2008 and .net 3.5.
2. I can create a new user when using AD users and groups on the server.
3. We are using identity impersonate and the user has full access to AD.
4. I can create the user on my local development machine.
5. This is on a Windows 2008 server using .net 3.5

Here is the code we are using:

```
        newPassword = GeneratePassword()
        ctx = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain",containerDistinguishedName)
        user = New UserPrincipal(ctx, userName, newPassword, enabled)

        ' Force the user to change the initial password on first logon
        user.ExpirePasswordNow()

        ' Commit the new object to Active Directory
        user.Save()

        ' Return success
        Return newPassword
```

Comment: Did you try creating a DirectoryEntry on the AD from that machine?  Do you have similar problem?

Comment: I can create a user from that machine.

Comment: I know you can create a user from that machine.  I am trying to help you to do troubleshooting.  I don't think you can get any good answer given your problem is very unique to your environment.  To troubleshoot this problem,  I suggest you to try using PrincipalContext with SimpleBind.  Then, you can see the plain text network traffic.  Download wireshark and capture the network traffic.  It's also worth to compare the result with a simple program that just create a new DirectoryEntry on the AD.  Also, remember to use SimpleBind.

Comment: ok, i understand.  I will perform these actions and see what I can find.

Comment: Here is what we found, referencing the internal alias for our LDAP server fails ("LDAP.Company.Com"), but if we use the direct IP or Machine name for the user.Save() everything functions perfectly.  Working to identify the issue with the alias and will update if we find something.

Comment: @brain Please update your question and include the code on what's working and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server may be the thing  that is not connected to the domain. This is possibly due to the machine being cloned and reusing the SID or name of the machine. Are you able to manage active directory users from this machine using the active directory users and groups tool?

Comment: Yes.  That is the part that does not make a lot of sense to me.